# notepad++ regular expression to strip XML attribute

Tags: notepad++

```
<option value="price">Price1</option>
<option value="3price">Price2</option>
<option value="36price">Price3</option>
<option value="39price">Price4</option>
```

How to use notepad++ R/E to replace value="*"
the output expected like,

```
<option>Price1</option>
<option>Price2</option>
<option>Price3</option>
<option>Price4</option>
```

I used `^value(.*)` but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression should work as you want, for the sample data provided:

```
 value="[^"]*"
```

Note that there is a space at the start of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

This works for the provided text

```
\svalue="\w*"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regular expression

```
value=[0-9A-Za-z]
```